# 2 C++ typedefs refer to each other - iterators

Tags: c++

C++

I would like to create two types of maps, each of which returns an iterator
to the other. I have cut down my code to the following, which gets syntax
errors because CacheList is not defined when encountered in the declaration
of AddressMap. Is there some way to do this ?

```
typedef map<void*,CacheList::iterator> AddressMap;
typedef map<void*,AddressMap::iterator> CacheList;
```

Comment: I don't think it's possible. The only solution I can think of is making one of them a map<void*,void*>

Comment: If AddressMap is defined to just use the same kind of iterator as CacheList, and CacheList is defined to just use the same kind of iterator as AddressMap, then at no point has the actual iterator definition been defined.

Comment: I believe @bcurcio is correct -- to be stored in a container, a type must be *complete*, and I see no way to make both iterator types complete.

Comment: It makes me think of two people going to a restaurant. When asked for their orders, they both say, "I'll have what he's having." The server walks away.

Comment: Could make one or both use a pointer to an iterator.

Comment: @bcurio You should post that as an answer. All things considered, it actually looks like a perfectly palatable solution.

Comment: The way you intend to use map container is wrong. Rethink your code.